# Seeking datasheet of electronic component: Part no: CCII01, Current Conveyor, OEM=LTP Electronics LTD, Oxford, UK

Tags: analog, current-source

I seek the datasheet of what seems to be an obsolete electronic component made by a company in Oxford UK known as "LTP Electronics Ltd", which appears to have been dissolved.  The product is known as "CCII01", and its datasheet is cited in several recent papers (for an example refer note 1 below), its citation appears (typically) as follows:

LTP Electronics LTD (1993) CCII01 Current Conveyor Data Sheet. LTP Electronics LTD, Oxford, UK.

For context, this question is related to a previous question, link below:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/673480/341959

I would be grateful for any assistance, thanks in advance.

Note 1:
https://file.scirp.org/Html/3-7601263_83224.htm

Comment: I was myself unable to locate a commercial datasheet, but I did find an internal schematic of the device in https://hippo.feld.cvut.cz/UserFiles/File/ADS-E/CC_introduction.pdf, figure 26. Is that of any use, or do you need values from the actual commercial datasheet?

Comment: @Nanofarad:  Many thanks, that is indeed a useful reference, however, I was hoping to find the actual datasheet.  The product itself contains two such current-conveyors, which makes it particularly attractive for high-speed-ish applications such as instrumentation amplifiers, and precision full-wave rectifiers (absolute value), as that reference you supplied shows on pages 582 & 583.

Do you have any idea if the product is still available, or if it perhaps has evolved into something different - it was 30 years ago, after all.  Cheers.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no idea. I wasn't even alive then, and I've never come across this product before this post. As for modern products, most of my high-speed analog design is on-chip in integrated circuits, and my instinct would be to try to design and lay out my own cell with a CCII± (± as the case may be) from the schematic and try to qualify it well enough for my application - which unfortunately does not translate well to helping find an existing IC that exposes that function.

Answer (score 3):

After Fabio posted [his answer pertaining ideal rectifiers](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/673480/121003) I also tried to find the CCII01 Current Conveyor Data Sheet (as a matter of fact, only the first page is shown in the [linked handouts](https://cas.ee.ic.ac.uk/people/dario/files/E416/cc_handout07.pdf), page #16) and I did not succeed. However I think that a very similar device is the OTA (operational transconductance amplifier) part of the [OPA615](https://www.ti.com/product/OPA615). Note that

- the device slew rate is not specified but the propagation delay and rise and fall times are and their magnitude is in the \$(1.4\div 2)\text{ ns}\$ range.
- the device bandwidth is \$>700\text{MHz}\$ under various operating conditions.

The different characteristics of the device are shown from page 6 to page 8, and give a vivid idea of what this amplifier architecture is capable to achieve.

Comment: Many thanks for pointing out that part, Daniele, that does indeed have very impressive speed.  Figure 35 of the datasheet clearly shows this as a classic OTA.  And the fact that the datasheet is dated 2004 and the device is still active and available is encouraging.  Thanks again!

Comment: Just to add: The OPA860 & OPA861 are worth looking at as pure OTAs, but they have all the classic compromises that plague OTAs: very high speed (80MHz @gain=5, 900V/us, rise & fall times <5ns!), but poor DC performance (dc offset of 15mV, bias currents 6uA).